# How i install android toolkit on mac os X

Tags: android

i want learn android development. I have the mac os device version 10.6.4. please tell me how i install android sdk and ADK with proper method. I don't know anything about java and android  and basic requirements need to meet to android toolkit.

Comment: Google it: http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=How+i+install+android+toolkit+on+mac+os+X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Android SDK Install instructions:
[Android SDK Install](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

I didn't install on osx, but windows and linux posed to problem here. I'm guessing the same for OS X.

Comment: Thanks, this is i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have documented my experience installing android on OSX [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/androidmacsetup)